# Finding Source of a UNIX Signal from Coredump

Tags: unix, crash, gdb, signals, coredump

This has been long pending question in my mind. I see that GDB tells us the signal causing process termination.

How do I find the source of the signal from a core?

In two different occasions my two application received SIGEMT and SIGUSR1. I know that there are other applications in production which can send these signals.

Also, I know that the sender information can be seen within running program and the data would be present in  **siginfo_t structure**. But I don't have that luxury and in fact we don't have handler for this signal at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recent-enough versions of the Linux kernel store this information in the core file.  And, recent-enough versions of gdb can read it.  Then you can use `print $_siginfo` with a core file just as you would when debugging live.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Recently, I killed a process by SIGABRT, but the $_siginfo showed 'void'. Any idea why? FYI, I am using NetBSD. Another question is to find out process id and parent process id from the core-dump .

Comment: FTR, the source PID of a signal is stored in `si_pid` field.

Answer (score 3):

You can also read this information from core dump by `eu-readelf`:

```
$ eu-readelf --notes coredump | head

Note segment of 3180 bytes at offset 0x4a0:
  Owner          Data size  Type
  CORE                 336  PRSTATUS
    info.si_signo: 6, info.si_code: 0, info.si_errno: 0, cursig: 6
    sigpend: <>
    sighold: <>
    pid: 28046, ppid: 3774, pgrp: 28046, sid: 3774
    utime: 0.000000, stime: 0.002895, cutime: 0.000000, cstime: 0.000000
    orig_rax: 35, fpvalid: 1
```

Note `info.si_signo: 6`, which means that process was killed by SIGABRT.

Comment: This seems to be the friendliest choice for cross environments as you do not require a cross gdb to extract this information. Any regular eu-readelf in the host works